# Listing of all events, to see why Tinymce doesn't focus?

Tags: javascript, events, contenteditable, tinymce-4

Using the latest TinyMCE 4 in [Inline mode](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php), I was noticing sometimes (rarely, randomly) the focus event doesn't seem to fire, therefore some changes in my `editor.on('focus'` listener don't run. Oddly enough there is no ajax call that seems to cause this lag.

In efforts to debug this, I was noticing there is no `editor.on('all'` event-handler as Backbone has, and on [beforeExecCommand](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.BeforeExecCommand) doesn't handle all listeners like Loadcontent etc.

Is there an easy way to list events to see how some listeners aren't getting fired, or other way to debug weird race-condition in MCE editors starting up?

Answer (score 0):

There are things I use to debug events:

- Visual Events: its a small chrome plugin that as the name suggests shows you a visual representation of the event handlers for each of the DOM elements
- Chrome developer tools' event breakpoints: You can set a breakpoint on any type of event. Perhaps some handler in your code is being fired first and calling event.stopPropagation()

[image: Chrome developer tools event breakpoints]